# How do I make the response from Python's requests package be a "file-like object"

Tags: python, python-requests, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I am hitting a webservice with Python's `requests` library and the endpoint is returning a (very large) CSV file which I then want to stream into a database.  The code looks like this:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    stream_csv_into_database(response)
```

Now when the database is a MongoDB database, the loading works perfectly using a `DictReader`:

```
def stream_csv_into_database(response):
    .
    .
    .
    for record in csv.DictReader(response.iter_lines(), delimiter='\t'):
        product_count += 1
        product = {k:v for (k,v) in record.iteritems() if v}
        product['_id'] = product_count
        collection.insert(product)
```

However, I am switching from MongoDB to Amazon RedShift, which I can already access just fine using `psycopg2`.  I can open connections and make simple queries just fine, but what I want to do is use my streamed response from the webservice and use psycopg2's `copy_expert` to load the RedShift table.  Here is what I tried so far:

```
def stream_csv_into_database(response, campaign, config):
    print 'Loading product feed for {0}'.format(campaign)
    conn = new_redshift_connection(config) # My own helper, works fine.
    table = 'products.' + campaign
    cur = conn.cursor()
    reader = response.iter_lines()
    # Error on following line:
    cur.copy_expert("COPY {0} FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '\t'".format(table), reader)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

The error that I get is:

> file must be a readable file-like object for COPY FROM; a writable file-like object for COPY TO.

I understand what the error is saying; in fact, I can see from the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#copy) that `copy_expert` calls `copy_from`, which:

> Reads data from a file-like object appending them to a database table (COPY table FROM file syntax). The source file must have both read() and readline() method.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to make the `response` object be a file-like object!  I tried both `.data` and `.iter_lines` without success.  I certainly do not want to download the entire multi-gigabyte file from the webservice and then upload it to RedShift.  There must be a way to use the streaming response as a file-like object that psycopg2 can copy into RedShift.  Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`response.raw` file object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw), but take into account that any content encoding (such as GZIP or Deflate compression) will still be in place unless you set the `decode_content` flag to `True` when calling `.read()`, which psycopg2 will not.

You can set the flag on the `raw` file object to change the default to decompressing-while-reading:

```
response.raw.decode_content = True
```

and then use the `response.raw` file object to `csv.DictReader()`.

Comment: I didn't think about wrapping `raw`.  Brilliant.